# Basic Javascript click function not loading

Tags: javascript

I am just trying to change the font attribute via a click function real beginner stuff, however I want to check if the element has been clicked a second time and do something if so.

```
var clicks = 0;
document.getElementById('button2').click(function(){
  clicks++;
  if(clicks%2===0){
    document.getElementById('demo2').style.fontSize='22px';
  } else{
    document.getElementById('demo2').style.fontSize='12px';
  }
});
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: where is the script tag below the html or in the head?

Comment: have you used document.onload = function() {}

Comment: its .onclick = func or addEventListener

Comment: click() is not an event listener

Comment: Just toggle a class, so much easier to maintain.

Comment: @epascarello is correct though that would be much easier the maintain and it would be as easy as .onclick = () => demo.classList.toggle('class-name')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not using an event listener instead?

According to the mozilla documentation (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click), the `click` function does not expect a function that defines the behavior of the click.

Try the following:

```js
var clicks = 0;
document.getElementById('button2').addEventListener('click', function(){
  clicks++;
  if(clicks%2===0){
    document.getElementById('demo2').style.fontSize='22px';
  } else{
    document.getElementById('demo2').style.fontSize='12px';
  }
});
```

```html
<button id="button2">Click me</button>
<div id="demo2">Hello</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/onclick
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

.click fires a click, it doesn't watch for them

```js
var clicks = 0;
document.getElementById('button2').onclick = function(){
  clicks++;
  console.log(clicks)
  if(clicks%2===0){
    document.getElementById('demo2').style.fontSize='22px';
  } else{
    document.getElementById('demo2').style.fontSize='12px';
  }
};
```

```html
<div id="button2">button2</div>

<div id="demo2">demo2</div>
```

This is what you should do though just toggle a class look how much code is removed and it does the exact same thing :)

```js
const button = document.querySelector('.button2');
const demo = document.querySelector('.demo2');

button.addEventListener('click', () => demo.classList.toggle('large'));
```

```css
.demo2 {
  font-size: 12px;
}

.large {
  font-size: 22px;
}
```

```html
<div class="button2">button2</div>

<div class="demo2">demo2</div>
```